# How to play webrtc playback in VideoJs

Tags: webrtc, video.js

I have tried two use cases to play webrtc playback on videojs.

After getting MediaStream from webrtc and add like the following:

```
player.src({src:webRTCAdaptor.remoteVideo.srcObject});
```

I'm getting `(CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED)`  error.
If i do like following, I'm not getting any error but video does not play either.

```
var vid=player.tech().el();
vid.srcObject=webRTCAdaptor.remoteVideo.srcObject;
```

Calling `player.play()` doesn't change anything.

Does anybody has any insight about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite the play function to achieve，like this

```
if (player) {
  const videoDom = player.tech().el()
  videoDom && (videoDom.srcObject = stream)
  player.play = () => {
    videoDom.play()
  }
  player.play()
}
```